# Foreign key value of a table is not getting auto-updated in Hibernate 5

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have the following book and author entities with oneToMany relationship from author to book

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Author")
public class Author {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;
private String name;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "author", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private List<Book> bookList;

gettters/setters

}
```

and

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Book")
public class Book {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;
private String title;

@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "authorId")
private Author author;

getters/setters
}
```

my controller

```
@PostMapping("/author")
public ResponseEntity<?> save(@RequestBody Author author) {
    long id = bookService.save(author);
    return ResponseEntity.ok().body("New Book has been saved with ID:" +id);
}
```

dao class

```
@Override
public long save(Author author) {
    sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(author);
    return author.getId();
}
```

I am calling the above web service using following input:-

```
{
"name":"Herbert shilde",
"bookList":[{
    "title":"My Book"   
}]
}
```

In my database the author table is inserting the correct data but the book table is not inserting the foreign key of the corresponding record. As you can see in the below image that the authorId in the book table is null. I am using hibernate 5.

Author table

[image]

Book table

[image]

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Debug your code and check if the authorId of your books is filled.

Comment: The question is: why would it put the `authorId` there? It would have to look the book by it's title (which may not even be in the database) and then update it with the new `authorId` - all by itself, because nowhere in your code have you specified it.

Comment: when i call the session.save(author) it inserts the data in the author table and the data of the corresponding child in the book table. But it doesn't save the authorId in the book table which it should as it is storing the other data as well

Comment: Try introduce `referencedColumnName` in `@JoinColumn` annotation

Answer (score -1):

Change

```
@JoinColumn(name = "authorId")
```

to

```
@JoinColumn(name = "authorId", referencedColumnName = "id")
```